# How can I list and access every instance of an EJB deployed to different servers

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

So firstly, I realise that EJB instance access is meant to be transparent, but I'm wondering how others might tackle this problem.

My problem is thus: I have a set of EJB containers or servers that I can deploy to and I have a (plain vanilla) java program that I would like to run multiple instances of, one per server, and manage individually.

I can easily remake this java program into an EJB and hence take advantage of EJB deployment etc... which would be ideal. The only problem is that of accessing each instance separately.

How would you go about this? What's possible and what's necessary to get it going? I'd prefer direct listing and access via the server cluster, but I'm open to any other idea that might work, like a centralised instance list.

Thank you all in advance,
Loren